# Laravel programmatically commands will not work with users

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, vue.js

Hi I am trying to run commands with buttons I created. Some commands must send an email to a user, but I keep getting 500 internal server errors. Also, how do I filter the user data to retrieve email address of currently logged in user?

Here is my route:

```
    Route::get('/admin/systemadmin/index', 'CommandsController@index')->middleware('permission:page-view-admin-systemadmin')->middleware('Analyse');
    Route::post('/admin/artisan/commands/run', 'CommandsController@runCommand')->middleware('Analyse');
```

Here is my controller:

```
      public function index() {
          $users = User::all();



           $commands = [
             [
                'id' => 1,
                'signature' => 'sync:whatever',
                'user' =>'',
                'title' =>'Sync Whatever',
                'groupID' => 1,
                'groupName' => 'First Group'
             ],

             [
                 'id' => 2,
                 'signature' => 'send:smsNotification',
                 'user' =>'users',
                 'title' =>'Send SMS',
                  'groupID' => 3,
                  'groupName' => 'Notification'
               ],
        ];

           return view('admin.systemadmin.test')->with(
           [
              'users' => $users,
              'commands' => collect($commands)
           ]
       );
     }

        public function runCommand(Request $request){
          $users = User::all();
          $signature = $request->input('signature');
          $command =  Artisan::call($signature);
          return response($command);
         }
```

Here is my blade.php:

```
<div v-for="(commands, groupName) in groupedCommands">
      <h4>@{{ groupName }}</h4>
      <div class="btn-group" v-for="command in commands">
        <commands-component
                :entity-config="commandConfig(command.id, command.signature, command.user, command.title, command.groupID, command.groupName)">
                <input style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:value="command.title">
        </commands-component>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My Vue:

```
    commandConfig: function(ident, signature, user, title, groupId, groupName){
            $data = {

                id: { text: 'commandModal' + ident, id: null },
                modalTitle: title,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        buttonTitle: 'Run Command',
                        buttonClass: 'btn btn-success pull-right',
                        submitUrl: {
                            url: '/admin/artisan/commands/run',

                        },
                    }
                ],
                attributes: [
                {name: "message", displayName: "Are you sure you want to proceed with the command?", type: "action-text",  col: "12" },
                {name: "signature", displayName: "Command Signature", type:'text', col:"12"}
                ],
                data: {
                    signature:signature + ' ' + this.users[0].email,
                    user: user
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 500 can refer to a number of things. Please put a couple of var_dump's into your function and proceed to the url that calls the function that is throwing an error. Then tell us which specific lines are causing the error. We can't help you if you're not specific enough about your problem.

Comment: This is one of the errors:
            "file": "C:\\git\\portal\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\Entities\\CommandsController.php",
            "line": 254,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
            "type": "::"
        },

Comment: One of the main problems that laravel has, is that the errors that it gives back to the user are completely useless. You need to find the error by yourself.